# Corba COS Naming service list all nodes

Tags: java, namespaces, corba

I have a name list consisting of 4 contexts. Context 1,2 and 3 are binded to the root node, and context 4 is binded to context 2. I am able to list the name of context 1-3 but I cant get context 4.

It is only listing nodes at the first level. I think that if I check each node, check if it has sub-nodes and then list them that will work but I am not sure how do do that. Here is my code. I have two methods to list the contexts

```
import java.io.*;
import org.omg.CORBA.*;
import HelloNaming.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.* ;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.*;

public class HelloNamingClient
{     

public static void main(String args[])
{
try{
    NameComponent nc[]= new NameComponent[2];


    ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);


    org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
    NamingContext rootCtx = NamingContextHelper.narrow(objRef);



    final int batchSize = 7;
            BindingIterator b ;
            BindingListHolder bList = new BindingListHolder() ;
            BindingIteratorHolder bIterator = new BindingIteratorHolder();

            rootCtx.list(batchSize, bList, bIterator) ;
            for (int i=0; i<bList.value.length; i++) {
                 System.out.println(bList.value[i].binding_name[0].id) ;
    }


NamingContextExt ncc =
          NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references(
        "NameService"));



    BindingListHolder bl = new BindingListHolder();
            BindingIteratorHolder blIt= new BindingIteratorHolder();
    ncc.list(1000, bl, blIt);

    Binding bindings[] = bl.value;

       for (int i=0; i < bindings.length; i++) {

                int lastIx = bindings[i].binding_name.length-1;


                if (bindings[i].binding_type == BindingType.ncontext) {
                  System.out.println( "Context: " +
                    bindings[i].binding_name[lastIx].id);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Object: " +
                      bindings[i].binding_name[lastIx].id);
                }
    }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR : " + e) ;
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }


}
}
```

Comment: please post your output - you forgot to recursively handle contexts in your for loop, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Each context is a separate CORBA object which needs to be queried individually just like the root naming context.  The following modification does this recursively and prints out '[contextN...].objectN':

```
import org.omg.CORBA.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.* ;

public class HelloNamingClient
{     
  public static void printContext( NamingContext nc, String parent )
  { 
    try {
      final int batchSize = 1000;
      BindingListHolder bList = new BindingListHolder( );
      BindingIteratorHolder bIterator = new BindingIteratorHolder( );

      nc.list( batchSize, bList, bIterator );

      for ( int i=0; i < bList.value.length; i++ ) {
        NameComponent[] name = { bList.value[i].binding_name[0] };
        if (bList.value[i].binding_type == BindingType.ncontext) {
            NamingContext context = NamingContextHelper.narrow( 
                nc.resolve( name ) );
            printContext( context, parent + name[0].id + "." );
        } else {
            System.out.println( parent + name[0].id );
        }
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR : " + e) ;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try{
      ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);

      org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
      NamingContext rootCtx = NamingContextHelper.narrow(objRef);

      printContext( rootCtx, "" );

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("ERROR : " + e) ;
      e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
  }
}
```